# Extract Pixel Data in Processing

Tags: processing, pixel, capture

Using the capture video in processing, I want to understand how to set up a small section of the camera feed that the camera will constantly scan. Within that defined section, I want the camera to look for a change in brightness (i.e the brightness now becomes dark.) If the brightness changes I just want it to return 'shadow detected.' Can anyone help me get started? I am very new to this language.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get a small section of the camera(or any image) using PImage's [get()](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html) method to which you pass a bunch of coordinates describing of your section rectangle(x,y, width, height).

This is also known as a region of interest (ROI) in computer vision.

Once you retrieve this region, you can process it.
Here a minimal example showing how to get the ROI and process it (in this case simply doing threshold based on the mouse position:

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;
int w = 320;
int h = 240;
int np = w*h;

int roiX = 80;
int roiY = 60;
int roiW = 160;
int roiH = 120;
PImage roi;

void setup(){
  size(w,h);
  cam = new Capture(this,w,h);
  cam.start();
}
void draw(){
  image(cam,0,0);
  if(roi != null){
    //process ROI
//    roi.filter(GRAY);
    roi.filter(THRESHOLD,(float)mouseX/width);
    //display output
    image(roi,roiX,roiY);
  }
}
void captureEvent(Capture c){
  c.read();
  roi = c.get(roiX,roiY,roiW,roiH);
}
```

You can get the brightness of a pixel using the [brightness()](https://processing.org/reference/brightness_.html) function.
This means you can get the average brightness of your ROI by adding the brightness levels for each pixels, then dividing the result by the total number of pixels:

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;
int w = 320;
int h = 240;
int np = w*h;

int roiX = 80;
int roiY = 60;
int roiW = 160;
int roiH = 120;
PImage roi;

void setup(){
  size(w,h);fill(127);
  cam = new Capture(this,w,h);
  cam.start();
}
void draw(){
  image(cam,0,0);
  if(roi != null){
    //process ROI
//    roi.filter(GRAY);
    roi.filter(THRESHOLD,(float)mouseX/width);
    //display output
    image(roi,roiX,roiY);
    text("ROI brightness:"+brightness(roi),10,15);
  }
}
void captureEvent(Capture c){
  c.read();
  roi = c.get(roiX,roiY,roiW,roiH);
}
float brightness(PImage in){
  float brightness = 0.0;
  int numPixels = in.pixels.length;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numPixels; i++) brightness += brightness(in.pixels[i]); 
  return brightness/numPixels; 
}
```

If you've set your ROI to cover the bright area, you should see the average brightness go down as the shadow appears. Simply using a threshold value in a condition should allow to act on it:

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;
int w = 320;
int h = 240;
int np = w*h;

int roiX = 80;
int roiY = 60;
int roiW = 160;
int roiH = 120;
PImage roi;

float brightness = 0.0;
float shadowThresh = 127.0;

void setup(){
  size(w,h);fill(127);
  cam = new Capture(this,w,h);
  cam.start();
}
void draw(){
  image(cam,0,0);
  if(roi != null){
    //process ROI
//    roi.filter(GRAY);
    roi.filter(THRESHOLD,(float)mouseX/width);
    brightness = brightness(roi);
    if(brightness < shadowThresh) println("shadow detected");
    //display output
    image(roi,roiX,roiY);
    text("ROI brightness:"+brightness,10,15);
  }
}
void captureEvent(Capture c){
  c.read();
  roi = c.get(roiX,roiY,roiW,roiH);
}
float brightness(PImage in){
  float brightness = 0.0;
  int numPixels = in.pixels.length;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numPixels; i++) brightness += brightness(in.pixels[i]); 
  return brightness/numPixels; 
}
```

Hopefully these examples are easy to read and understand.
Note that this aren't as fast as they can be.
Be sure to also check out the video examples that come with Processing (**Examples > Libraries > video > Capture**), especially these: **BrightnessThresholding,BrightnessTracking**

If you want to learn more about techniques like these you should look into computer vision and the OpenCV library. There is a very nice [OpenCV  Processing library](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing) which you can now easily install via **Sketch > Import Library... > Add Library...** and select **OpenCV for Processing**. It also comes with examples on using brightness.

This covers the pixel manipulation side, but another important aspect of doing this sort of development is setup. It's crucial to have a reliable setup: it will make your life easier. What I mean by that is, in your case:

- having control over the camera: being able to control auto white balance/brightness/etc. as automatic adjustments may throw off your values.
- having control over the scene: making sure you reduce of risks of accidental lights messing with your tracking, or something bumping over the camera or object you're tracking.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thank you for your detailed explanation - I look forward to playing around with this and altering it for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the camera data you are analysing is a PImage, you can apply filters to the data to get it into a Black/White or grey scale form. The docs on PImage Filter modes: https://processing.org/reference/filter_.html should be useful.

You will probably have to do a pixel analysis - there may be a library to help here, but you can get an array of pixels from the filtered PImage, loop through it and check the values against your baseline values to see if they are brighter or darker. If they are grey scale in the 0 - 255 scale, you can tell if they are lighter if the number if higher than the baseline, or darker of the number is lower.